# Can you read a file regardless of the file name into python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some background: Currently using Python3, was wondering if it was possible (so long as the file is in the same directory as the .py file) to open a file regardless of the file name and just go by file type? In my current program I want the user to be able to drop a file such as "test.pdf" and just have my program automatically recognize the .pdf and read that file in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google python glob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glob`:

```
import glob

filelist = glob.glob("*.pdf")  # Get all pdf files in the current folder

for file in filelist:
    do_stuff(file)
```

Comment: You check for `*.pdf` types but say you are getting all txt files?

Comment: @megargayu typo, in the first version I was searching txt as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to list files in a directory using `*` notation

For example

```
In [6]: glob.glob('Downloads/*.pdf')
Out[6]:
['Downloads/file1.pdf',
 'Downloads/file2.pdf'
```

This will help you find the file as long as you know the extension (I used the `Downloads` folder to demonstrate how you can add a path to the query).  You didn't articulate in the question if you could have more than one but that might be a case to watch out for

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at python [os-listdir](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) and python [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

But anyway:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith("pdf"):
        print(file)
```